# Create a button or an icon which can be double clicked to run a .sh file

Tags: linux, shell

I am a beginner in shell script file. I want to use shell script because I'd like to run a bevy of programs which are in different languages at almost the same time. So, my `.sh` file may look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
echo "Hello, $USER!"
python3 a.py
gcc trial.c
......
```

But I want it to be more user-friendly. As a result, I came up with sometiong like button or icon. While I have no idea how to fullfill it. Could someone share some great ideas?

Comment: this link might be helpful https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries

Comment: Understand that any *button* or *icon* within a desktop is a desktop specific 'thing' for lack of better words (there are opendesktop standard that many desktops follow). What you are asking is *"How do I associate a shell script with a desktop icon, menu item, or taskbar button so I can click on the 'thing' and have it launch my script?"* First, your script must be *executable* (e.g. `chmod +x scriptname`), then it is just a matter of following the desktop specific steps to assign a launcher to the script (e.g. `kmenuedit` in KDE, etc..)